# Finding sign of acceleration

Tags: accelerometer, game-physics, android-sensors

How can one find if device is accelerating or decelerating from 3-axis accelerometer? sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2) will give magnitude of acceleration, but to find if it is acceleration or deceleration I guess some vector math has to be done. If anyone could direct me or link me with some source, that would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no perfect solution to your problem: a decelleration is an acc with direction opposing the actual speed, and you have no (good) way to access the speed of the device.

just to give you some ideas: you could keep an array of the last N values (as vectors (x y z)) of acc(t). If you move the accellerometer in some direction and then stop, I'd expect to have in that array something like { A1 A2 A3 A4 D1, D2, D3, D4 } where all the A are vectors more or less in the choosen direction (magnitude will vary) and all the D are vectors in the opposite of the choosen direction.
The dot products of two A vectors would be positive, as of two D vectors, but dot product Ax*Dy will be negative and this should give you an hint of "the accellerometer is stopping"...

another thing to note: in my experience the accellerometer data varies a lot, therefore it is usually best to calculate the "moving average" of those values and work with those

Comment: yes, once I get event.values, I high-pass filter them which is "moving average", and its output is the acceleration values I'm working with. 
Could you elaborate more on A and D values please. Do you mean looping through array and dot product - ing each consecutive pair until I find negative result?

Comment: yes, or + - + (two sign changes)... or ++-++ or more if needed

Comment: Thank you. Seems like sensible idea. but I'll pass and search for another method. Too complicated